# How to pass data to child without specifying it in props

Tags: reactjs

Recently we got Context support in react.
Lets take next example:

```
<Consumer>{value => <Child value={value} />}</Consumer>
```

How do i make a component that sends "value" same way to its child?
I mean

```
<MyComponent>{value => ...}</MyComponent>
```

Comment: You can also use [child] property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make your component to use `render props callback pattern` like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   state = {
      value: 'abc'
   }
   render() {
      return React.Children.only(this.props.children)(this.state.value)
   }
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
<MyComponent>{value => ...}</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe a [higher order component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)?

```
function withContext(Component) {
  return WithContext = (props) => (
    <Consumer>
     {
       value => <Component {...props} value={value} />
     }
    </Consumer>
  )
}

let MyComponent = ({ value }) => (
  <div>
    {value}  // if value is something that can be rendered
  </div>
)

MyComponent = withContext(MyComponent);
```

or with [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html):

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <Consumer>
    {value => props.children(value)}
  </Consumer>
)

const example = (
  <MyComponent>
   {value => <div>{value}</div>} // children prop has to be function now
  </MyComponent>
)
```